# How do I add a global button (for all entities) on the CRM 2013 Command Bar

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

I want to create a global button for all the entities.

I tried the following:

1. Created a sample solution with entity Application Ribbon
2. Opened the Application Ribbon Entity in Ribbon Workbench
3. Under Command Bar -> Home . Placed a button besides New Record

However after publish I am not able to view the button.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Were there any errors at the time of the publish?. As i recall the Ribbon Workbench Buttons needs also the command defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is from Mithilesh Kumar, and can be found on this page:
https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/155542

You need to find the Group where you want to show the Button.

1. If you want to show on the Home Page for all Entity, find the Group as below and place the Button in this Group.
   [image]
2. If you want to show in the Forms of all Entity, you need to place in the Group in the Form Area, shown below
   [image]

Hope that clarifies

Answer (score 1):

Modifying the XML you need to rely on the `{!EntityLogicalName}` keyword inside the location.

You can find a tutorial here:

http://blog.webfortis.com/adding-global-ribbon-buttons-for-all-entities-in-dynamics-crm

Comment: Prieto hi i already tried the mentioned tutorial however the problem i m facing with that is it is visible majorly on all entities except Accounts & Contacts. Is it like i have take in consideration the sequence number?

Comment: The link is broken now.

Comment: a text version without screenshots is available here https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/webfortisblogunleashingyourcrm/archive/2014/02/11/adding-global-ribbon-buttons-for-all-entities-in-dynamics-crm the company was acquired and they removed all their post, sorry