# CRM 2013 Onprem: logged in users accessed area in CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2013

We want to check what areas are used by user when they login to CRM. I have tried the recentlyvieweditems.
Is there any other way we can achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there is any solution or way to find out what area are clicked unless you login as that user and check what that user clicked.

The closest you can reach to get some insight for users and which entites they are accessing.

[Organization insight solution](https://www.crmsoftwareblog.com/2017/06/dynamics_365_crm_organization_insights/)

Answer (score 0):

You have to capture those user telemetry data like - pages navigated, opened entity records, clicked ribbon buttons, etc [using Application Insights](https://github.com/Power-Maverick/ApplicationInsightsManager) or your own Database through your own API for all the breadcrumbs.

There is no other native solution other than Org Insights, that too available from 2016 onwards IIRC. Later they took different diversions during CRM online version upgrades.

Answer (score 0):

You may try the EnableRule of application level command bar button to run your custom JS code to log user navigation. I haven't used it ever, but this is what I would try in your given scenario and I don't see any reason if it wouldn't work.

1. Create new custom entity/table with User ID/Name and URL attributes/columns
2. Create a application level command bar button
   [How do I add a global button (for all entities) on the CRM 2013 Command Bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29160459/how-do-i-add-a-global-button-for-all-entities-on-the-crm-2013-command-bar)
3. In button's enable rule, Add user id/name and document.location.href values as a new record to the custom table.
   [Create entity record through Javascript , CRM 2013 , SDK.Rest.CreateRecord](https://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/12241e51-8c07-4089-8582-86473d0def2c/create-entity-record-through-javascript-crm-2013-sdkrestcreaterecord?forum=crmdevelopment)

4. Don't forget to return false from the code in 'enable rule' so that the button should not actually be shown anywhere in the application.